# Get category id when SEO URL is turned on

Tags: php, plugin-development, categories

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Members
*/

   function myFilter2($query) 
    {

        if ($query->is_category)
        {
            $currently_listing_categories = $query->query_vars['category__in'];             
            print_r($currently_listing_categories);
        }

    }

    add_filter('pre_get_posts','myFilter2');
?>
```

This plugin display the category ids when the url is not SEO friendly

> http://domain.com/wplab/wpla4/?cat=4

. but when I turn on SEO

> http://domain.com/wplab/wpla4/category/members/

the array is empty

how can I get the category id with SEO friendly urls

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to  get current cateogry in wp :

```
function getCurrentCatID(){

 global $wp_query;
 if(is_category() || is_single()){
  $cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
 }
 return $cat_ID;
```

}

```
echo getCurrentCatID();
```

Just found for you, try this,

```
if(isset($wp_query->get_queried_object()->cat_ID))
{
    $cur_catId = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->cat_ID;
}
if(issset($wp_query->get_queried_object()->ID))
{
    $cur_postId = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->ID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFilter2($query) 
    {

        if ($query->is_category())
        {
            $currently_listing_categories = $query->get('cat');             
            print_r($currently_listing_categories);
        }

    }

    add_filter('pre_get_posts','myFilter2');
```

you should use

1, `$query->is_category()` instead of accessing the **is_category** variable directly.

2, `$query->get()` to get query value.

Just one tip, you can always use the code below to output the contents.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($query);
exit;
```